# Simple integration using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I came across this simple integration problem involving a substitution.

Let

*$$I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin x}{\sin x + \cos x}   \,dx $$
Use the substitution  $ u = \frac{\pi}{2} - x $ to show that
$$I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos x}{\sin x + \cos x}   \,dx $$*

Well I know $ \sin x = \cos( \frac{\pi}{2} - x)$ and  $ \cos x = \sin( \frac{\pi}{2} - x)$ as well as

$$ du = - dx $$

But I can't seem to see how to get the the given answer.  I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Thanks but PricessEev has answered my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given substitution, you have
$$
I = \int_{\pi/2}^0 \frac{\sin( \frac \pi 2 - u)}{\sin( \frac \pi 2 - u) + \cos( \frac \pi 2 - u)} \, (-1) \, \mathrm{d}u
$$
By the stated trigonometric identities,
$$
I = \int_{\pi/2}^0 \frac{\cos(u)}{\cos(u) + \sin(u)} \, (-1) \, \mathrm{d}u
$$
We exchange the upper and lower bounds: if you recall, for integrable $f$, $\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = - \int_b^a f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$. By linearity, this negates the $-1$ attached to the differential. So we have
$$
I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(u)}{\sin(u) + \cos(u)} \, \mathrm{d}u
$$
Finally, the name of the variable doesn't matter. We might as well let $u$ be replaced with $x$:
$$
I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x) + \cos(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
Therefore, $I+I$ is, using the initial expression you start with for one, and the above for the other, and the rule
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x + \int_a^b g(x) \, \mathrm{d} x
= \int_a^b \Big( f(x) + g(x) \Big) \, \mathrm{d} x
$$
(for integrable $f,g$) we get
$$
2I = I+I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \left( \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x) + \cos(x)}  + \frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x) + \cos(x)}  \right) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
Add the fractions: the result will simplify nicely, and you will be able to solve for $I$.

Comment: Thanks.  I had that answer but thought there was an alternate way of doing the problem.  Thank-you so much for clarifying my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let
$$I_1=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}\mathrm{d}x,I_2=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}\mathrm{d}x,$$
then consider $I_1+I_2$ and $I_1-I_2$.

Comment: I am supposed to use the substitution though.